# Executing SQL IN function

Tags: python, django

I have an management command

```
from django.db import connection
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand   

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = "[id]"

    def handle(self, id, **options):
    ids = []
    if '-' in id:
        splitted = id.split('-')
        for n in range(int(splitted[0]), int(splitted[1])+1):
            ids.append(n)
    else:
        ids.append(id)
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT content FROM log WHERE id IN %s', [ids])
```

I can run this by entering command name and specify paramater (id)

When I run `command 200-205`, the for loop returns a list:

```
ids =[200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205]
```

And puts this in the query:

```
SELECT content FROM log WHERE id IN (200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205)
```

Briljant!

When I run `command 200` ids will be:

```
ids = [200]
```

Executing the query returns an error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1")
```

Seems like `SELECT content FROM log WHERE id IN (200)` is not working while it should.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK to me, but I'm not fluent in those Django libraries.  A couple of (perhaps obvious) workaround ideas: (1) construct two different SQL statements to be executed; in the one-ID case, it's a simple `SELECT content FROM log WHERE id =` (2) again for the one-ID case, make an array with two instances of the desired ID, so that Django constructs this SQL: `SELECT content FROM log WHERE id IN (200, 200)`.  In other words,

```
else:
    ids.append(id)
    ids.append(id)
```

Comment: If I do that i get an error: _mysql_exceptions.Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''200''

Comment: Did you go with option (1) or option (2)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing some parentheses?

```
SELECT content FROM log WHERE id IN 200
```

vs.

```
SELECT content FROM log WHERE id IN (200)
```

Comment: It seems to go perfect when adding the parenthesses but then it goes wrong when running the command with a range: 200-205... The following error occurs: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: If you can print/display/log the SQL statement you're trying to execute before executing it, you might spot the problem very quickly.

Comment: Can you monitor the commands being sent to your RDBMS? If you're using SQL Server, you can use SQL Profiler to see all the commands. Otherwise, we need to see more information on the new problem to help (either create a new question or *add* the new details to this one)